# Ruby - Pathname.glob - matching hidden and non hidden files

Tags: ruby

I am using **Pathname.glob** to match files.

`Pathname.glob("**/*")` matches only non-hidden files

`Pathname.glob("**/.*")` matches only hidden files

Is there any way to match both?

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pathname.glob("**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
```

Source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob